# Too many open files, is my file-handling correct?

Tags: java, file-handling

We're running below code snippet periodically and are accessing several thousands of files per run. The system sometimes starts mentioning "too many open files". Not being too familiar with Java I wondered if something is wrong with this piece of code. I understood the try-construction takes care of closing files at all times. Or should a finally be added to prevent files remaining open?

```
...
try 
 ( 
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
     InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
     LineNumberReader in = new LineNumberReader(isr);
)
{
      if (in != null)
      {
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                  strLine = strLine.substring(3);
                  printLine(bw, strLine);
            }
      }
} catch (Exception e)
{
        e.printStackTrace(jcsErr);
}
...
```

Comment: If you are running on Unix like operating system lsof should help you to list the open files by the Java process.

Comment: For what it’s worth, there is no need to check `in != null`.  In Java, the `new` operator *always* returns a non-null object.

Comment: thanks, did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

When the *system* (and not *Java*) is reporting "too many open files", then you hit a limitation of your system (more precise, of your operating system configuration).

The code snippet as such is ok, but when used in a multithreaded program, it can still cause the reported issue (1000 threads each one reading a file would do the job …).

Comment: Thanks. The code snippet is called thousands of times as a subroutine checking a list of files reported elsewhere in the code. Could it be the proces in accessing the files is that fast, things are accumulating and could there be a relation with OS parameters like tcp_keepalive_time, tcp_keepalive_intvl and tcp_keepalive_probes? Currently the settings on our system are 60s, 75s and 9. 
I assumed, once a file is accessed and read in the code snippet, it is closed properly (bc of the try-construction, be it that we're not explicitly closing the streams).

Comment: But looking at the output of lsof on our Linux system while running the code, we see a lot of open files on the system related to the specific PID of the java-proces, as well as half open connections and many, many files that state "can't identify protocol".

Comment: After some time (around 25-30 minutes), we see the number of open files normalize. However, when we start the code again at an earlier point since the last run, open files accumulate, in the end running up to a level exceeding OS settings (ulimit), and reporting too many open files.

Comment: I remember that their was a bug causing files being kept open for some time by the JVM although the Java program had closed them already. But I cannot remember if that was fixed already and/or if there was a way to circumvent it. I do not even remember wether this was a general issue or existing only on some Linux/UNIX versions and/or JVMs.